# Merge files & keep bigger file if duplicates?

Tags: terminal

I have several folders each containing several hundred thousands of txt-files, let's call them f1, f2, f3, f4.

I want to move all the files into one folder, say F0 and – if there are duplicate files – keep the bigger files (kb or line count) and delete the smaller ones.

Is there a way to do this relatively quickly?

Many thanks in advance!

edit: Upon trying a simple `mv`-command, I got `-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long`. So I believe that's another hurdle to be overcome.

Comment: `mv` alone won't solve the "take the bigger file" part anyway, you are looking at a combination of `find`, `test`, `stat` and `mv`.

Comment: @nohillside Ok, thanks -- I discarded the idea of testing for size since I need to weed out other errors in non-duplicate files after this step anyways. `find raw_data2 -name '*.*' -exec mv {} raw_data1 \` solved the issue in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the size test

```
find f1 f2 f3 f4 -type f -exec mv {} f0/ \;
```

should do the trick.

With a line count (so the file with more lines wins) and assuming that all files are text files it gets a bit more sophisticated:

```
find f1 f2 f3 f4 -type f -execdir sh -c \
    '[[ ! -e f0/"$1" || $(wc -l < "$1") -gt $(wc -l < f0/"$1") ]] && \
         mv "$1" f0/' _ {} \;
```

And finally if you want to compare for file size you need to replace both occurrences of `wc -l <` (including the `<`) with `stat -f '%z'`.

PS: For hundred thousands of text files both `find` approaches will take a while. The second one using `stat` should be significantly faster than using `wc` though.